# Freshman calculus question in Hartshorne, chapter V.

Tags: calculus, algebraic-geometry

In exercise 4.10, we are asked to prove an identity using "freshman calculus"
[image]

I have tried combining the given inequalities in order to arrive at the desired identity, and all things have failed.

My question is: what function should be studied here. And also it would be more beneficial if you could explain "why" this specific choice.

Comment: Briefly looking at this, I would try differentiating the desired identity with respect to various variables to see if the hypotheses then imply positivity of the derivatives, and see if the quantity in question is positive for small values of the variable in question (so that positivity of the derivative implies positivity for larger values as well).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I'll interpret $a-b_i-b_j>0$ as being for $i\neq j,$ otherwise why not just write $a-2b_i>0$?)

First observe that it is equivalent to the following problem:

> Given reals $a$ and $0\leq b_1\leq b_2\leq b_3\leq b_4\leq b_5\leq b_6$ such that $a\geq b_5+b_6$ and $2a\geq b_2+b_3+b_4+b_5+b_6,$ we have $a^2\geq \sum_{i=1}^6 b_i^2.$

(If $a$ satisfies some "sharp" assumptions $a>\cdots$, so does a slightly smaller $a',$ and then a "weak" conclusion $a'\geq \cdots$ implies $a>\cdots$. The equivalence can be shown by approximation by rationals, scaling and sorting.)

I'll just going a bit beyond frehsman calculus just for explanation. Fixing $a$, this problem is maximizing a strictly convex function over a polytope: taking a convex combination of two vectors $b$ satisfying the hypothesis will produce a smaller $\sum b_i^2.$ This means the largest $\sum b_i^2$ is at an extreme point of the polytope defined by the hypothesis. I won't rely on this, but it should give some faith that a case analysis won't go on forever.

Consider a vector $b$ attaining the maximal possible $\sum b_i^2$ while satisfying the hypothesis. My first step would be to just write down any inequalities I can see:

- either $b_2+b_3+b_4+b_5+b_6=2a$ or $b_5+b_6=a$ (otherwise $b_6$ can be increased)
- $b_1=b_2$ (otherwise $b_1$ can be increased)
- $b_5\leq a/2$ (otherwise $b_5+b_6>a$)
- $b_5=b_4.$ (For any fixed sum $b_5+b_6=S,$ the maximum of $b_5^2+(S-b_5)^2$ over $b_5\in [b_4,S/2]$ is attained on the boundary, and $b_5=a/2$ is smaller)

It is tempting to say that we can increase $b_2$ or $b_3$ to get $b_2+b_3+b_4=a,$ but that is (a priori) only possible if $b_4\geq a/3.$ So it looks like we have to consider cases.

### Case 0: $b_5+b_6<a$

I neglected this case in the first version, and to avoid rearranging things too much I'll rely on the later cases here; their proofs are independent.

In this case $b_2+b_3+b_4+b_5+b_6=2a.$ Holding $b_1=b_2$ and $b_4=b_5$ constant, since $b_3+b_6$ is fixed, the maximum of $b_3^2+b_6^2$ is attained by reducing $b_3$ as much as possible. So either $b_1=b_2=b_3,$ or we've reduced to the case $b_5+b_6=a.$ This means we only need to consider $b=(b_1,b_1,b_1,b_5,b_5,b_6).$

Holding $b_1$ constant, the maximum $2b_5^2+b_6^2$ is attained on the boundary so $b_5=b_1$ or $b_5=b_6,$ or we've again reduced to the case $b_5+b_6=a.$ There are then just two parameters, $b_1$ and $b_6.$ The worst possible $b_1$ is either minimal, which reduces to $b_5+b_6=a,$ or $b_1$ is maximal, which gives $b_1=b_6=\tfrac 2 5 a,$ which gives $\sum b_i^2=\tfrac{24}{25}a^2.$

### Case 1: $b_4\leq a/3$

In this case, $b_2=b_3=b_4,$ otherwise we could increase $b_3$ or $b_2$.
This gives $\sum b_i^2=4b_4^2+(a-b_4)^2,$ which is some quadratic with positive $b_4^2$ coefficient. Maximizing over $b_4\in [0,a/3],$ any maxima are on the boundary, but both $b_4=0$ and $b_4=a/3$ give $\sum b_i^2=a^2.$

### Case 2: $b_4\geq a/3$

In this case, $b_2+b_3+b_4=a,$ otherwise we could increase $b_3$ or $b_2$. Maximizing $2b_2^2+(a-b_4-b_2)^2$ over $b_2\in [a-2b_4, \tfrac 1 2(a-b_4)],$ any maxima are on the boundary.

#### Case 2a: $b_2=\tfrac 1 2(a-b_4)$

To recap, $b$ is $(\tfrac 1 2(a-b_4),\tfrac 1 2(a-b_4),\tfrac 1 2(a-b_4),b_4,b_4,a-b_4),$ and $\tfrac 1 3 a\leq b_4\leq \tfrac 1 2 a.$ Maximizing $\sum b_i^2,$ the maxima are on the boundary. But $b_4=\tfrac 1 3 a$ gives $\sum b_i^2=a^2.$ And $b_4=\tfrac 1 2 a$ gives $\sum b_i^2=\tfrac{15}{16}a^2<a^2.$

#### Case 2b: $b_2=a-2b_4$

To recap, $b$ is $(a-2b_4,a-2b_4,b_4,b_4,b_4,a-b_4),$ and $\tfrac 1 3 a\leq b_4\leq \tfrac 1 2 a.$ Maximizing $\sum b_i^2,$ the maxima are on the boundary. But $b_4=\tfrac 1 3 a$ and $b_4=\tfrac 1 2 a$ both give $\sum b_i^2=a^2.$

---

This process also gives the locations of the maxima:

- $(0,0,0,0,0,a)$
- $(0,0,\tfrac 1 2 a,\tfrac 1 2 a,\tfrac 1 2 a,\tfrac 1 2 a)$
- $(\tfrac 1 3 a,\tfrac 1 3 a,\tfrac 1 3 a,\tfrac 1 3 a,\tfrac 1 3 a,\tfrac 2 3 a)$

For the original problem, take any strictly smaller vectors, and all permutations.

Comment: In case 1, it seems that you have only summed 5 of the 6 terms.

Comment: @لافظ بن لاحظ: well spotted. Actually I think there was quite a big gap in my argument - I don't see why I can assume $b_5+b_6=a.$ Hopefully fixed now.